# jquery autocomplete suggestion trigger search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

okay iM using jquery autocomplete and Everything works fine but I want it to trigger the search button when a suggestion is selected. the code i have is this.

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        select: function (event, item)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 13){
                $('#IDofMYform').submit()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the value to the form input before submitting. If you don't, your form is submitted before it has a chance to populate the input.

Something like :

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //Set the value
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);

        // Submit the form
        $('#IDofMYform').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you I got it, worked perfectly the problem was a comma after source value. Thanks.